# Force iOS app to launch in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am developing an app for iOS 5, which have to run in landscape mode. My problem is that I cannot get it to flip initially.

I have tried the adding "Initial interface orientation" set to "Landscape (right home button)"
and adding the following method to my view controller:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

I can wrap my head around how it is supposed to work. (I found the code [here](http://blog.typpz.com/2010/02/12/iphone-programming-how-to-force-your-app-to-run-in-landscape-mode/))

I am also wondering how to use the "Supported Device Orientation" available in the Xcode 4.2 project setup, it does not seem to do anything.

I have been looking around the website and have not been able to find an example that solves my problem.

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628668/468724

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your application’s Info.plist file, add the `UIInterfaceOrientation`
  key and set its value to the
  landscape mode. For landscape
  orientations, you can set the value
  of this key to
  `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft`
  or
  `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`.

Lay out your views in landscape mode and make sure that their autoresizing options are set correctly.

Override your view controller’s `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` method and return YES only for the
  desired landscape orientation and NO
  for portrait orientations.

Comment: Thank you.
I did do as you described. I have more then one subview and found out I had to override the method on all controllers before I got it to work.

Comment: if in your info.plist you put the UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight above the other landscapes then you can start your app on landscape

Answer (score 11):

use the following in appDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```

also set the required orientations in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

//Here are some iOS6 apis, used to handle orientations.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) 
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations - (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
```

Comment: shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: not called help me its appreciated

Comment: @JigPatel use some of these new methods in ios6 `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0)
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`

Answer (score 1):

When you click on your project's name in XCode and select your target under TARGETS, under Summary tab there's a visual representation of the supported device orientation settings. That was how I managed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

i think if you at the supported interface orientations in the project plist it will work. just add a new line called "Supported interface orientations" and make it of array type and add 2 items for each of teh landsape views u want. havent tested this just a quick guess

Answer (score -2):

Try this this will help you, write this code in you viewdidload.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
```