# Landscape app for ipad doesn't have home screen landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating landscape app for iPad, but when I run the application I found the home screen displays as portrait. How can I solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force iOS app to launch in landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940338/force-ios-app-to-launch-in-landscape-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the target, in that select only Landscape Left and Landscape Right option in "Supported Device Orientations. And also in your roo view controller set

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{  
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);    
}
Thank you for your reply but I have already implement this method like above...now what should I do?

Comment: check the info.plist once the "Supported interface orientations (iPad)" must contain only below two values...
<array>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
 <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>

Comment: I check the info.plist, "Supported interface orientation contains the same value.. so can you please give another solution....??

Comment: Go to your .xib file in that select the view and change the orientation property(in 4th tab) of your view to "Landscape"

Comment: sorry but at there also orientation is landscape.. :(

Comment: Can you give me another solution..??

Comment: Nothing extra required... I think you are missing something. Can you just post the screen shot of your app running in portrait and also the info.plist file.

Comment: Can you also search "shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation" in entire application and make sure that you are returning YES only for landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your app only supports landscape orientations in your Project Settings (unselect 'Portrait' and 'Upside Down'):

[image: Xcode 4 Project Settings]

View Controllers that support landscape should say they do, too:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have already implement this method but still I can't get landscape home screen

Comment: Than you for your reply, but i have already implement this method

Answer (score 0):

add this methord

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

// Return YES for supported orientations
NSLog(@"Changed interface orientation");

return ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        );

}
```

Comment: - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{  
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);    
}
Thank you for your reply but I have already implement this method like above...now what should I do?